# Can i define modulus function like this: $f(x) = x,x>0 ; -x,x≤0$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, functions

The image is shown here
[image: the image is shown here]

I found the defenition of modulus function from a text book as
$$f(x) = \begin{cases} x,& x \ge 0, \\
-x,& x < 0\end{cases}$$

My doubt is that will it be correct if I write mod function as
$$f(x) = \begin{cases} x,& x > 0, \\
-x,& x \le 0\end{cases}$$

will it be correct if I write so? I just changed the equality sign.

Comment: The two are equally good.

Comment: When $x=0$, $x=-x$

Comment: $$\text{$0=-0=|0|$}$$

Answer (score 0):

Yes, your function is exactly the same as the function from the textbook.

You only "changed" the function at $x=0$; you said that at $x=0$, $|x|=-x$, instead of $|x|=x$. This makes no difference, since $0=-0$, so $|0|=-|0|$.

Thus, your function is also correct.